# How to color conditionally to character in label the annotations bars

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, annotations, rstatix

I would like to concitionally color annotations bars in ggplot to label character. I am posting the following example here

```
library(ggplot2)
library(rstatix)

color_mapping <- function(label) {
  if (grepl("A", label)) {
    return("orange")  
  } else if (grepl("B", label)) {
    return("purple") 
  } else {
    return("aquamarine") 
  }

}

my_data <- data.frame(
  group1 = c("A", "B", "C"),
  group2 = c("D", "E", "G"),
  p = c(0.01, 0.05, 0.001),
  y.position = c(0.8, 0.7, 0.9),
  label = c(
    "A vs D: p=0.037  -  ns",
    "B vs E: p=5.78e-06  -  ****",
    "C vs D: p=0.005  -  *"
  )
)

my_data$color <- sapply(my_data$label, color_mapping)

my_plot <- ggplot(my_data, aes(x = group1, y = y.position)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  stat_pvalue_manual(data = my_data, label = "label", colour = my_data$color)
```

But unfortunately it does not seem to work. Could you suggest some alternatives? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `ggpubr::stat_pvalue_manual` works with `geom_text` behind the scenes so you need to add a kind of `scale_color_manual` layer to deploy the correct colors; since you didn't write your groups as factors then I'll use `scale_color_identity` to preserve the correct order of colors:

```
  ggplot(my_data, aes(x = group1, y = y.position)) +
    geom_col() +
    stat_pvalue_manual(data = my_data, label = "label", color = "color") +
    scale_color_identity(palette = my_data$color) +
    theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

If you want to fill the bars with the respective colors, just change `geom_col() +` to `geom_col(aes(fill = my_data$colors)) +` and add `scale_fill_identity(palette = my_data$color) +`. Last but not least note that the correct parameter to be filled in `stat_pvalue_manual` is `color` instead of `colour`.